# Draw segments of circle on xna

Tags: c#, xna

How do I draw a circle sector (as in a slice of pizza shape) in xna?

I'd like to use one as a timer indicator, so would like to be able change its angle dynamically.

In an ideal world I'm looking for something like this:

```
Drawsector (float startAngle, float endAngle, ... )
```

Does such a thing exist?

And if it does - how would I go about drawing a more graphically involved one (as opposed to just block colour)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. [XNA only provides an API for drawing primitive elements called surprisingly *primitives*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice_methods.aspx).

All is not lost because drawing a circle can be viewed as simply drawing a series of very short interconnected line segments, small enough that you can't tell they are lines, but not too small so as to be inefficient.

In XNA you would draw a `PrimitiveType.LineStrip`.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.primitivetype.aspx):

> The data is ordered as a sequence of line segments; each line segment is described by one new vertex and the last vertex from the previous line seqment. The count may be any positive integer.

e.g. (from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196414.aspx#ID4EUF))

```
GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(
    PrimitiveType.LineStrip,
    primitiveList,
    0,   // vertex buffer offset to add to each element of the index buffer
    8,   // number of vertices to draw
    lineStripIndices,
    0,   // first index element to read
    7    // number of primitives to draw
);
```

You would need to create your own function to determine the vertices that match the arc you want to draw.  You should save that into a permanent index and vertice buffer rather than performing a `DrawSector()` all the time in your game loop.

### Tell me more

- *[Drawing 3D Primitives using Lists or Strips](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196414.aspx#ID4EBE)*